# calculating a top 5 in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rating

Hey I've made a rating system in php and mysql and now I want to select a top 5,
I've made something but if a user adds a rating (with the max) it's nr 1 ranking.

How do you guys do it in php and mysql ?

the table looks like this:

-- id

-- mid

-- uid

-- rating

The rating is a number from 1 to 5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's mid and uid? Are you keeping track of the number of votes? Just require a minimum number of votes to be counted in the top 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@chaos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155664/calculating-a-top-5-in-php-and-mysql/1155676#1155676) points out, this is the idea:

```
SELECT `mid`, SUM(`rating`) AS `total`
FROM `rating`
GROUP BY `mid`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

However, to ensure that not articles with very few ratings get into the top-5 you can add a threshold, allowing only articles with more than X ratings will show up in the result, perhaps giving a more accurate picture of the top 5:

```
SELECT `mid`, SUM(`rating`) AS `total`, COUNT(1) AS `nrRatings`
FROM `rating`
GROUP BY `mid`
HAVING nrRatings > 5 // This is the threshold. Only articles with more than
                     // 5 ratings will be considered
ORDER BY `total` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)`, or `COUNT(rating)` if rating is nullable, is more idiomatic than `SUM(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `mid`, SUM(`rating`) AS `total`
FROM `rating`
GROUP BY `mid`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your wording, looks like a rating of 1 is the highest?  ORDER BY should then be ASC.  I think AVG() would be more appropriate than SUM().  Totally agree with the threshold idea, so something like this (shameless c/p rewrite; thx @Machine :P):

```
SELECT `mid`, AVG(`rating`) AS `avg_rating`, SUM(1) AS `nrRatings`
FROM `rating`
GROUP BY `mid`
HAVING nrRatings > 5 
ORDER BY `avg_rating` ASC
LIMIT 5
```